# Are polar sets Borel measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m\geq2$ is called polar if for each point $x$ in $E$ there is a superharmonic function $u(x)$ on a neighborhood of $x$ such that $u$ is not identically $\infty$ and $u(x)=\infty$. We know that such a set is Lebesgue measurable, and my question is: Is a polar set Borel measurable?

Comment: Is every subset of a polar set polar? Does there exist a polar set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ (an uncountable Borel polar set would suffice)? If both of these have a YES answer, then a simple cardinality argument works -- there are $\mathfrak{c}$ many Borel sets and $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ many subsets of a set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}.$